# Antiderivative of a simple function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I solve the following indefinite integral containing inverse $\cosh$? Does it have any antiderivative?

$$I(t,a) = \int \frac{\text{arccosh}\ t}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}} dt.$$
The case $a = 1$ is elementary:
$$I(t,1) = \dfrac{(\text{arccosh}\ t)^2}{2}.$$

Comment: Merely because a function is simple, or elementary, does not mean that its integral is elementary as well. Take for instance $I(t,a)=\int e^{t^a}dt$, for any $a\neq0,1$.

Comment: As it turns out, $a=2$ has no elementary solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+arccosh%28x%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2-4%29%29

Comment: Do you really need the antiderivative, or will some definite integral be also of interest?